# Jackson XML annotations: Extract single string value from XML element with attributes

Tags: java, xml, jackson, pojo

I'm using Jackson XML annotations to convert an XML document from an external API into a POJO. One element in the XML is giving me a bit of trouble. Most of the elements have no attributes, and just a text value such as:

```
<title>Title Here</title>
```

I'm having some trouble with one element though, which has an attribute, like this:

```
<urgency id="UrgCaution">Caution</urgency>
```

I just want to pull out the text value "Caution" and store it in a string. I originally tried this way in my Java class:

```
public class Item {
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "urgency")
    private String urgency;
}
```

But that results in the following error:

```
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not construct 
instance of Item: no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from 
String value ('Security')
at [Source: java.io.ByteArrayInputStream@328ff654; line: 40, column: 21]
```

"Security" is the text of an xml attribute called "tags" that appears later in the document.

I tried making the following change, which eliminated the exception, but results in me getting a null value for urgency in the POJO.

```
public class Item {
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "urgency")
    @JacksonXmlText
    private String urgency;
}
```

I feel like I'm missing something obvious here. What's the best of way of converting this element's text into a String field on a POJO using Jackson?

Here's the full class and XML document I'm working with.

XML:

```
<rss version="2.0">
    <channel>
        <title>Title</title>
        <description>Description</description>
        <copyright>Copyright info</copyright>
        <ttl>5</ttl>
        <pubDate>Thu, 27 Apr 2017 17:21:40 GMT</pubDate>
        <item>
            <title>Title of event in U.S.</title>
            <description>Description here</description>
            <fulldescription>Full description here</fulldescription>
            <link>http://www.website.com</link>
            <pubDate>Thu, 27 Apr 2017 17:13:48 GMT</pubDate>
            <locations>
                <location>
                    <name>New York, NY</name>
                    <latitude>40.714502</latitude>
                    <longitude>-74.006998</longitude>
                    <code>NYC</code>
                    <city>New York</city>
                    <state>New York</state>
                    <country>United States</country>
                    <region>North America</region>
                </location>
            </locations>
            <source>AP</source>
            <urgency id="UrgAttention">Attention</urgency>
            <categories>
                <category id="CatTransp">Transportation</category>
            </categories>
            <destinations>
                <destination code="NYC" id="US" lat="40.714502" longitude="-74.006998">New York, New York</destination>
            </destinations>
            <designations />
            <related />
            <tags>Railway disruptions</tags>
            <guid>3d64388fc639475dc9aeaabf81ee87bd</guid>
        </item>
    </channel>
</rss>
```

Now the classes. Getters and setters omitted for brevity. There's also a Location, Destination and Category class, but I'll not include those unless they are necessary.

Root class:

```
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "rss")
public class FeedRoot {
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "channel")
    private FeedChannel channel;
}
```

Channel class:

```
public class FeedChannel {
    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(localName = "item", useWrapping = false)
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "item")
    private List<Item> items;
}
```

Item Class (Json properties are for marshalling results into JSON, but removing them does not change the outcome):

```
public class Item {
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "title")
    private String title;

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "description")
    private String description;

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "fulldescription")
    @JsonProperty("full_description")
    private String fullDescription;

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "link")
    private String link;

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "pubDate")
    @JsonProperty("publish_date")
    private String pubDate;

    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(localName = "locations")
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "location")
    private List<Location> locations;

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "source")
    private String source;

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "urgency")
    private String urgency;

    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(localName = "categories")
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "category")
    private List<Category> categories;

    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(localName = "destinations")
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "destination")
    private List<Destination> destinations;

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "related")
    private String related;

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "tags")
    private String tags;

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "guid")
    private String guid;

    //getters and setters below here, no annotations
}
```

Error when attempting to parse (namespaces omitted):

```
"Could not read document: Can not construct instance of 
com.namespacestuff.Item: no String-argument constructor/factory 
method to deserialize from String value ('Railway disruptions')\n at 
[Source: java.io.ByteArrayInputStream@45563ea1; line: 42, column: 32] 
(through reference chain: com.namespacestuff.FeedRoot[\"channel\"]-
>com.namespacestuff.FeedChannel[\"item\"]->java.util.ArrayList[5]); 
nested exception is 
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not 
construct instance of com.namespacestuff.Item: no String-argument 
constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('Railway 
disruptions')\n at [Source: java.io.ByteArrayInputStream@45563ea1; 
line: 42, column: 32] (through reference chain: 
com.namespacestuff.FeedRoot[\"channel\"]-
>com.namespacestuff.FeedChannel[\"item\"]->java.util.ArrayList[5])"
```

Comment: I think *@JacksonXmlText* is not correct. Maybe you have to provide all the properties in the POJO.

Comment: Do you mean for the remaining xml elements? If so, I'm already doing that.

Answer (score 6):

To have this

```
<urgency id="UrgCaution">Caution</urgency>
```

you must create a POJO as below :

```
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "urgency")
public class Urgency {
    @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute=true)
    String id;
    @JacksonXmlText
    String text;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATE**

As the OP was updated after my answer, I add some consideration.

Even with the code provided, if I try to deserialize just the *Item* element, all is fine.

The issue is there just when all the *rss* element is involved.

Looking to the XML the issue looks on the *FeedChannel* definintion.

```
public class FeedChannel {
    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(localName = "item", useWrapper = false)
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "item")
    private List<Item> items;
}
```

I try to change this removing *useWrapper* and *localName* to *items*, then I changed the XML accordingly.

```
<items><item>...</item></items>
```

And all worked.

As I wrote below, you don't need the *@JacksonXmlText* annotation for the *urgency* property.

It looks like a bug on *Jackson* as the *useWrapper* changes the behaviour not just for your current list.

The urgency property attribute *id* convert the property to an array.
If you remove the attribute, all is fine.

So far, I think this is a Jackson library issue, and you should report to them the case.

---

**Original answer**

You miss to post all the code needed, as your error is not where you point I think.

I made an example that works:

Here is my POJO:

```
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "item")
public class Item {
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "field1")
    private String field1;

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "field2")
    private String field2;

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "urgency")
    private String urgency;

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "tags")
    private String tags;

    public String getField1() {
        return field1;
    }

    public void setField1(String field1) {
        this.field1 = field1;
    }

    public String getField2() {
        return field2;
    }

    public void setField2(String field2) {
        this.field2 = field2;
    }

    public String getUrgency() {
        return urgency;
    }

    public void setUrgency(String urgency) {
        this.urgency = urgency;
    }

    public String getTags() {
        return tags;
    }

    public void setTags(String tags) {
        this.tags = tags;
    }
}
```

Here is the test:

```
public class ItemTest {

    @Test
    public void readItemTest() {

        final String itemXml = "<item>\n" +
                "    <field1>Field1 Text</field1>\n" +
                "    <field2>Field2 Text</field2>\n" +
                "    <urgency id=\"UrgCaution\">Caution</urgency>\n" +
                "    <tags>tag</tags>\n" +
                "</item>";

        XmlMapper xm = new XmlMapper();

        try {
            Item myItem = xm.readValue(itemXml, Item.class);

            assert("Caution".equals(myItem.getUrgency()));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            assert(false);
        }

    }
}
```

No errors, no issues, it just work as expected.

Java 7

My dependencies:

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Curious. I'll edit the main post to include the full XML document and all annotations.

Comment: @MarkAbersold you updated the OP after my answer. No problem, I had update it.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Since I can't change the XML, this looks like something I'll just have to work around.

Comment: @MarkAbersold you can try defining a custom deserializer for the item property. This should work, but is much more code.